# SCRIPT438:the object does not support the property or method "matches"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer

My Code is working in Chrome, Firefox,  Safari and Microsoft Edge, but on Internet Explorer I see this error in the console:

> SCRIPT438:the object does not support the property or method "matches"

Can someone help?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var matches = e.target.matches('.open_section_btn');
  if (matches) {
    getApp(e);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? `matches()` is supported down to IE9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches. If you really are still using IE8 or lower, use the polyfill available from that link. Then I would strongly suggest you change your browser.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - IE9+ only have it with its prefixed name, `msMatchesSelector`.

Comment: Good point - I missed the caveat icon. I'd still suggest using the polyfill instead of the non-standard property name though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't support [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), but does support `msMatchesSelector`. The [MDN page for `matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) lists a polyfill to use prefixed versions if the unprefixed isn't available:

> ```
> if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
>   Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
>                               Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
> }
> ```

*(If you're bothered that that's just using assignment rather than `Object.defineProperty` to create a non-enumerable property [like I was], it turns out `Element.prototype.matches` **is** enumerable, so it's fine.)*

There's a longer one, but if you just need to support IE9+ and anything vaguely modern, that's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE version 9 or above, you can make it work using the `ms` prefix.
Check the full support list [here](https://caniuse.com/matchesselector)